# Bootstraps modal is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrapping

when I click on user logo the modal will display but it is not able to insert any data of run any script.can any one tell me how can I handle this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .modal-header, h4, .close {
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color:white !important;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
  }
  .modal-footer {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  </style>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>FOOD ATHOURITY</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
        <!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- font Awesome -->
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Ionicons -->
        <link href="css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Morris chart -->
        <link href="css/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- jvectormap -->
        <link href="css/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- fullCalendar -->
        <link href="css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Daterange picker -->
        <link href="css/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link href="css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="skin-blue">
        <!-- header logo: style can be found in header.less -->
        <header class="header">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <!-- Add the class icon to your logo image or logo icon to add the margining -->
               <div>FOOD ATHOURITY</div>
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
                     
                        <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu" id="myBtn">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:20px;"></i>
                               
                            </a>
                        </li>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><img src="a.png" height="70px" width="70px"> Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="background-color:blue;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
          <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
      
     
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
</script> 
      
      
      
      
                    </ul>
                </div>
    <div style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:10px; font-size:20px;" class="navbar-left" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
   <a href="#" style="color:white;"><strong>Moneeb</strong></a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#" style="color:white;"><strong>Basit</strong></a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#" style="color:white;"><strong>Nouman</strong></a>
   </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
            </nav>
   
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
            <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
                <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                <section class="sidebar">
                    <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
                    <div class="user-panel">
                        <div class="pull-left image">
                            <img src="img/avatar3.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left info">
                            <p>Hello, Jane</p>

                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- search form -->
                    <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type='submit' name='seach' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- /.search form -->
                    <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/widgets.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Widgets</span> <small class="badge pull-right bg-green">new</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                                <span>Charts</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/morris.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Morris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/flot.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Flot</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/inline.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Inline charts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                                <span>UI Elements</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/general.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> General</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/icons.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Icons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/buttons.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Buttons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/sliders.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Sliders</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/timeline.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Timeline</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Forms</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/forms/general.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> General Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/forms/advanced.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Advanced Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/forms/editors.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Editors</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Tables</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/tables/simple.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Simple tables</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/tables/data.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Data tables</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/calendar.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>Calendar</span>
                                <small class="badge pull-right bg-red">3</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/mailbox.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>Mailbox</span>
                                <small class="badge pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <span>Examples</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/invoice.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Invoice</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/login.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/register.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Register</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/lockscreen.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Lockscreen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/404.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> 404 Error</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/500.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> 500 Error</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/blank.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Blank Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <!-- /.sidebar -->
            </aside>
        </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

        <!-- add new calendar event modal -->


        <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery UI 1.10.3 -->
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Morris.js charts -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Sparkline -->
        <script src="js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- jvectormap -->
        <script src="js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- fullCalendar -->
        <script src="js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
        <script src="js/plugins/jqueryKnob/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- daterangepicker -->
        <script src="js/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
        <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- iCheck -->
        <script src="js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- AdminLTE App -->
        <script src="js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
        <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
        <script src="js/AdminLTE/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <style>
  .modal-header, h4, .close {
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color:white !important;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
  }
  .modal-footer {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  </style>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>FOOD ATHOURITY</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
        
    </head>
    <body class="skin-blue">
        <!-- header logo: style can be found in header.less -->
        <header class="header">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <!-- Add the class icon to your logo image or logo icon to add the margining -->
               <div>FOOD ATHOURITY</div>
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
                     
                        <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu" id="myBtn">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:20px;"></i>
                               
                            </a>
                        </li>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      

      
     
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
</script> 
      
      
      
      
                    </ul>
                </div>
    <div style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:10px; font-size:20px;" class="navbar-left" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
   <a href="#" style="color:white;"><strong>Moneeb</strong></a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#" style="color:white;"><strong>Basit</strong></a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#" style="color:white;"><strong>Nouman</strong></a>
   </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
            </nav>
   
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
            <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
                <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                <section class="sidebar">
                    <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
                    <div class="user-panel">
                        <div class="pull-left image">
                            <img src="img/avatar3.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left info">
                            <p>Hello, Jane</p>

                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- search form -->
                    <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type='submit' name='seach' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- /.search form -->
                    <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/widgets.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Widgets</span> <small class="badge pull-right bg-green">new</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                                <span>Charts</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/morris.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Morris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/flot.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Flot</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/charts/inline.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Inline charts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                                <span>UI Elements</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/general.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> General</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/icons.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Icons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/buttons.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Buttons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/sliders.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Sliders</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/UI/timeline.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Timeline</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Forms</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/forms/general.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> General Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/forms/advanced.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Advanced Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/forms/editors.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Editors</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Tables</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/tables/simple.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Simple tables</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/tables/data.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Data tables</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/calendar.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>Calendar</span>
                                <small class="badge pull-right bg-red">3</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/mailbox.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>Mailbox</span>
                                <small class="badge pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <span>Examples</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/invoice.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Invoice</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/login.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/register.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Register</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/lockscreen.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Lockscreen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/404.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> 404 Error</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/500.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> 500 Error</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pages/examples/blank.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Blank Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <!-- /.sidebar -->
            </aside>
        </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

        <!-- add new calendar event modal -->
      
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><img src="a.png" height="70px" width="70px"> Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="background-color:blue;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
          <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
         

    </body>
</html>
```